# previous date for multiple rows of same date in SQL

Tags: sql

I try to get the previous date for customer IDs.

The issue is that every customer ID has multiple rows for the same date with items they bought.

I need these rows in my data set.

I tried following, but this gives me the previous date for one row and the other rows get ignored:

```
LAG([date], 1, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY [shop_id], [customer_id] ORDER BY [date] ASC) AS [previous_date]
```

This is sample data and I need the "previous date" column:

```
shop_id    date      customer ID   items     previous date
------------------------------------------------------------
1111      2020/1/1        aaa       milk        NULL
1111      2020/1/1        aaa       cheese      NULL
1111      2020/1/1        aaa       bread       NULL
1111      2020/2/5        aaa       apple       2020/1/1
1111      2020/2/5        aaa       cherry      2020/1/1
```

Please advise, Thanks

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*, 
       max(date) over (partition by shop_id order by date range between unbounded preceding and interval '1 day' preceding) as previous_date
from t;
```

The above is standard SQL.  The syntax for the code snippet in your question suggests SQL Server.  If so, the simplest method is probably a lateral join:

```
select t.*, t2.date
from t outer apply 
     (select max(t2.date)
      from t t2
      where t2.shop_id = t.shop_id and t2.date < t.date
     ) t2;
```